# How do I add and control settings for social media sharing buttons on CiviCRM Petition pages?

Tags: social-media, petition

On the Edit Petition page, I have ticked the box for 'Allow sharing through social media', but on the live [petition webpage](https://conservationcouncil.org.au/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fpetition%2Fsign&sid=14), there are no social media buttons.
If I manually copy and paste the petition webpage link into a new post of Facebook, the preview card shows only the title of the website with nothing from the petition page.
I have an image in the body of the text on the Edit Petition page which shows up correctly on the petition webpage but does not appear in the Facebook post even after using the Facebook debugger to rescrape the page.
On the [Thank you page](https://conservationcouncil.org.au/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fpetition%2Fthankyou&pid=14&id=1&reset=1) after signing the petition (submitting the form), the social media buttons look like rubbish and give the results described above.
Please help:
How do I include social media share buttons on a petition webpage?
How do I change the social media settings of the petition to create a preview card that includes the petition title and custom description?
How do I get the image on my petition page to appear in social media posts?
Thanks.